# If for each $x \in \mathbb R$ there exists $n$ such that $f^{(m)}(x)=0$ for all $m \ge n$ then prove that $f$ must be a polynomial

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be an infinitely differentiable function such that for every $x \in \mathbb R$ there exists $n$ such that $f^{(m)}(x)=0$ for all $m \ge n$. I need to prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

It is trivial to show using Baire's theorem that $f$ must be a polynomial in some open ball, but since $f$ is not necessarily analytic I cannot apply the identity principle to obtain the desired result. I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: I suppose you could integrate $n$ times from the zero function, showing that all functions $f$ must be polynomials? Is there a flaw?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Well no, but that would only show that $f$ is a polynomial in the open ball, not all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: See answer in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial/64252#64252

Comment: @Gedgar I presume your answer is not intended to answer the question.

Comment: The chosen answer to that other question answers this question.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you